# How to get csdl, ssdl and msl specification from assembly which have EF model

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, reflection

I would like to get csdl, ssdl and msl specification from assembly which have EF model.

Using reflection:

```
//loading assembly
var assem = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyWithEF.dll);
//get model
var model = assem.GetExportedTypes().Where(t => t.BaseType.Name == ObjectContext").First();

//get specification
var csdlStream = assem.GetManifestResourceStream("Model1.csdl");
var mslStream = assem.GetManifestResourceStream("Model1.msl");
var ssdlStream = assem.GetManifestResourceStream("Model1.ssdl");

var csdl = XElement.Load(csdlStream);
var msl = XElement.Load(mslStream);
var ssdl = XElement.Load(ssdlStream)
```

Question is, how can I programatically get name of EDMX file that is needed to get these specifications. In this case "Model1".

Comment: Why did you want to get those resources?

Comment: I'm trying to write comparator between edmx model and db. (find out what is missing in db etc..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since csdl, ssdl and msl files are embedded in the assembly as resources, their names can be accessed by using 
[Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcenames.aspx)